# Error al hacer dos consultas a base de datos desde PHP en una peticion AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

tengo un problema , no sé si es incorrecto hacer esto, o tengo algo mal en mi código, pero explicaré mi problema. Desde una peticion AJAX en mi controlador en php hay un metodo que hace consulta a un metodo conexion para realizar consulta a base de datos. y funciona correctamente al hacer una consulta, pero al hacer otra consulta al mismo metodo del modelo, me regresa null, ni si quiera me regresa algun error si no que devuelve null y ya no se ejecuta nada de ninguna de las dos consultas. Tengo dias sin conocer la razón

```
public function guardarAviso($AvisoData, $tipo){
    
      $consultas = new avisoCancelacionModelo();
      //Primera consulta
      $historial = $consultas->guardarHistorial($AvisoData['modaltxtuuid']);
      //Segunda consulta
      $docRelacionado = $consultas->getDocsRelacionadosCFDI($AvisoData['modaltxtuuid']);
```

tanto guardarHistorial como getDocsRelacionadosCFDI estos metodos llaman en el modelo al metodo conexion que recibe la consulta y la ejecuta en SQL server, pero, me doy cuenta que no puedo realizar dos consultas al mismo metodo de conexion, no entiendo por qué, me regresa null cuando tengo las dos lineas, pero si comento una, me regresa correctamente el resultado de una consulta, el problema es al tener las dos consultas así que no se realizan los insert y las consultas. Alguien podria ayudarme? tengo dias batallando con esto. Estos son los me todos en el modelo

```
public function getDocsRelacionadosCFDI($Uuid)
    {
        $consulta = "EXEC proc_obtenercfdirelacionados '".$Uuid."'";
        $resultado = $this->conexionSQL($consulta, true);
        return $resultado;
    }
```

```
    public function guardarHistorial($UUIDviejo, $UUIDnuevo = 0)
    {
        $consultaINSERT = "INSERT INTO tabla1(folio, cfdiAntiguo) VALUES (6, '".$UUIDviejo."')";
         $result = $this->conexionSQL($consultaINSERT);
         return $result;
    }
```

Ambos metodos llaman al de conexionSQL donde se realiza la consulta, como menciono, las consultas estan bien, si hago una por una se realizan correctamente.
Este es el metodo de conexion

```
 private function conexionSQL($consulta){
    try{
        require("func_pagos.php");
        require("cnx_pagos_provs.inc");
        $cnx = Conecta_BD($host_conta,$db_conta,$user_conta,$pass_conta,"",$servms);
        mssql_select_db("$db_conta");

      }catch(Exception $e) {
        $resultado["estado"] = -6;
            return $resultado;
      }

        $q_mostrar=$consulta;

        $rs_mostrar = mssql_query($q_mostrar);

        if (!$rs_mostrar) {

            $resultado["estado"] = -5;
            return $resultado;
        } else {

          while ($data = mssql_fetch_assoc($rs_mostrar)) {


            $arreglo["data"][]=$data;
          }     
                    if(count($arreglo)==0){
                        $arreglo2 = array(
                            "UUID"=>null,
                            "Tipo"=>null,
                            "importefactura"=>null,
                            "fecha"=>null
                        );
                         $arreglo["data"][]=$arreglo2;
                    
                    
                }
                
                
           Desconecta_BD($cnx,$servms);

      return $arreglo;

    }
    }
```

Alguien podria ayudarme a comprender el por que no funciona cuando hago llamado a este metodo dos veces?

Comment: En tu caso, creo que lo ideal sería usar transacciones, se ejecuta la primera consulta, si tiene éxito se ejecuta la segunda y así hasta terminar, si alguna falla se devuelve

Comment: Hola Marco. Leo esto en tu pregunta: *tengo dias batallando con esto* y te voy a decir por qué: porque no estás depurando ni controlando errores en tu código. Si aprendes a depurar (sobre todo leyendo los logs de errores) y escribes un código controlado que incluya manejo de errores, te ahorrarás horas, días, meses perdidos en quebraderos de cabeza. Dejando de lado lo de los logs de errores (interésate seriamente por ese tema en un futuro) a tu código le falta controlar los errores. No puedes programar pensando que todo irá bien, todo lo contrario, debes programar pensando que todo irá mal...

Comment: ... y que tu tarea como programador es estar ahí cuando todo vaya mal para dar una respuesta adecuada. Dado que estás usando `try ... catch`, en `conexionSQL()` mete dentro del `try` todo el proceso de los datos. Tienes datos fuera del `try` que escapan a un control. Aún así no estoy seguro de que el código quede controlado, me parece que los fallos a las llamadas de `mssql_query()` invocan excepciones, si no lo hacen, tienes que establecer un control distinto de `try` para controlar los posibles fallos de la ejecución de consultas.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu consejo, soy programador novato y me sirve escuchar consejos de programadores con más experiencia, bueno, yo pensaba que tenia bien controlado mi codigo con el catch que regresa resultado y cuando rs_mostrar no está definido, pero ni siquiera regresa ese resultado, me regresa en javascript, en la llamada Ajax un vacío en response

Comment: incluso sí en la funcion guardarHistorial hago un return ejemplo return 1; en vez de result, tampoco me regresa ese 1, pero si hago el return arriba la linea $result = $this->conexionSQL($consultaINSERT) si me regresa el 1 el return, por eso no entiendo por que no ejecuta absolutamente nada del llamado a conecionSQL para abajo, aun que no retorne ese $result

Comment: Estás creando una conexión para cada consulta y, seguramente, ya usaste el total de conexiones disponibles para una petición. Debes conectar una sola vez a base de datos y usar la misma conexión para todas las consultas.